Is every self homeomorphism of the open disk conjugate to a homeomorphism extendable to the boundary?
Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid |z|<1\}$
Is it true to say that every homeomorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ is conjugate to a self homeomrphism of the disk extendable to a homeomorphism of $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$?
Is there a self homeomorphism of the disk which is conjugate to two self homeomorphism $f$ and $g$ of the disk   extendable to homeomorphisms of closed disk with different rotation number?
The rotation number is meant for restriction to the boundary

No. One can find a smooth homeomorphism of the open disk that takes each circle about the origin, say of radius r ≥ 1/2, to itself by a rotation by angle (r), satisfying (r) → ∞ as r → ∞. This cannot be extended to the closed disk.

@DanielAsimov Is not even conjugate to a extendable homeomorphism?

The "subtlety" as I see it is that a conjugacy need not extend to the boundary either

The issue with this question is really that there are two questions. I believe the first one is subtle, and I dont know how to decide whether @DanielAsimov's example is conjugate to a homeomorphism that extends to the boundary. I have no idea whether this is research level.

The second question can be answered negatively by using the concept of fundamental group at infinity, which is defined as $\pi_1^\infty(X):=\lim_{\leftarrow }\pi_1(X\setminus K)$, where the limit runs over all compact sets of $X$ and where the structure maps are given by inclusions and where all base-point issues are ignored. $\pi_1^\infty$ is only functorial if we restrict to proper maps and for the open disc, we just get $\mathbb{Z}$. A cofinal system is given by excluding larger and larger balls. Then the winding number at infinity can be defined this way.

This somewhat evades all the issues whether a homeomorphism can be extended to the given boundary and it is still clear that it is conjugation invariant. This part might not be research-level, but I dont think the fundamental group at infinity is included in many first year topology courses.

And I can tell you that even the fundamental group is not taught in all first topology courses. Source: I teach the only topology course in our university. (FWIW I did not design this course)

@VilleSalo  So we take  limit of  the  rotation number as circles approach  to infinity. Is not  necessary  to assume that $X\setminus K$ is  $f$ invariant. I  guess the  answer is  no  but it is  a  kind  of  caution and  math obsession

I  think  for  every  manifold $M$ with boundary  one  may  associate  a  normal  subgroup $H$ of $G=Home(M^{\circ})$  consist of  all  homeomorphism conjugate  to an extendable self  homeomorphism of $M^{\circ}$

The  reason  for  the  obsession: The  classical rotation number is  sensitive to datas one  can not  replace  a  home  f with fg

what can be  said  about the  structure of  $G/H$?  Is  there a Lie  group (finite  or  infinite dimensional)  structure on this  group?

I  am  aware of  invariance  of  rotation number under  conjugation but the  case of  non invariance $X\setminus K$ provoke the  obsession that:  is the  limit  $\frac{F^n(x)-x}{n}$ really exists? Any  reference?

@VilleSalo  "a conjugacy need not extend to the boundary either " Yes that is the point thanks. But I am not aware of  two extendable homemorphism which are conjugate on the interior but not on the  boundary. it seems that

@HenrikRüping in 1 dim. impossible  since the rotation number determine the conjugacy class  and  you said the rotation number is  well defined  but what  about higher dimension?

@VilleSalo So one may think to a refine version of cobordism theory: Assignment of a group to every cobordant triple $(M,N,W)$, with $\partial W=M \sqcup N$ the normal subgrouo H iof $G=homeo(W^\circ)$ consisting of self homeomorphisms extendable to the boundary

Correction: Self  homeomorphism  conjugate to an extendable homeomorphism

@HenrikRüping  Thanks for  introducing me  the "Fundamental group  at infinity"  I just find  a  paper  with the  same  title  1996, Topology. Befor  I read it I wonder how  the rotation number can reflect in fundamental group. I think the degree reflect on fundamental and  homology  not  rotation number?

@DanielAsimov Is there  a  homeomorphism of the  disk extendable  to  a  continuous  map  on the  boundary  which is  not  a homeomorphism(However its  degree must be  perhaps 1  according  to  the  concept of  "fundanmental  group at infinity"  discussed above
